# iOS - Swift3 - Google Analytics sending data, but analytics dashboard is empty

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

My events in Xcode are getting sent correctly, but my Google Analytics dashboard is 100% empty. I've been at it for hours and still nothing.

For instance (this works):

```
    //Create analytics for the screen
    if let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker {
        print("kGAIScreenName: \(kGAIScreenName)")
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Splash")
        if let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView() {
            tracker.send(builder.build() as NSDictionary as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        }
    }
```

And produces the following:

```
2017-01-07 18:04:37.185861 UpNextAlpha[582:122213] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:518): 
    Saved hit: {
        parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_s" = 27;
        "&_u" = ".oK9L";
        "&_v" = "mi3.1.7";
        "&a" = 0000000000;
        "&aid" = "com.xxx.xxx";
        "&an" = xxx;
        "&av" = "1.0";
        "&cd" = Splash;
        "&cid" = "xxx-xxx-xxx";
        "&dm" = "iPhone7,2";
        "&ds" = app;
        "&sr" = 750x1334;
        "&t" = screenview;
        "&tid" = "MY-ID-HERE-2";
        "&ul" = "en-us";
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = 000000000000;
        gaiVersion = "3.17";
    };
    timestamp = "2017-01-08 00:04:37 +0000";
}
```

So as you can see the code works, and the event is being sent - but there is nothing in the Google Analytics dashboard.

I've read a lot of posts that talk about the analytics dashboard not updating in real-time, and "taking a while," but this has been going on for over 12 hours and still nothing.

Comment: The last time I created a new google analytics account (~3 months ago) it took almost 24 hours for reports to start being populated

Comment: @MathewS That's nuts - especially for Google. Hopefully it's the same for me because I'm struggling here. Thanks for the heads up though...no other post I saw listed any kind of tentative timeframe.

Comment: Yeah @MathewS is right, our updates are not instant. And currently take about 24 hours to update as well